# Cities and Knights: Played to virtual deadlock

Tags: catan, catan-cities-and-knights, catan-traders-and-barbarians

Recently I have been playing cities and knights with fish and harbor master.  Victory points needed to win is 15.

The last two times we have played we have basically played to a deadlock.  No one with enough points to win, and no real way to get more victory points.  The only way to get additional points would be through the defender of catan, but by the time the pirate ship comes around the players in the running to win can match knight strength.

It has kind of ruined the game for me.  Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Let's see...

5 settlements 5VP
4 cities =8 VP
 
Longest Road = 2VP
Metropolis = +2VP (above the city it's on) (3 of them).
2 1VP progress cards

6 Defender of Catan VP's as well.

There is a progress card that allows removal of an opponent's knight. Time it for just before the barbarians, and make him pull one, then you get your VP for Defender of Catan.

Remember - Defender of Catan is earned for there being enough knights... and being the man with the most strength when that happens.

If you have misplayed so that your cities and settlements are more than 2 apart, then you've simply played poorly.

It is possible that, through particularly poor play, you might be stuck at 13 VP; if all the VP cards are out, and you're out of spots to play, it is time to call it, and I'd call it a double loss.

I'll note however: The Fishermen of Catan does not increase VP to win (unless you hold the old boot), and the Harbor Master variant only increases VP needed by 1.

Answer (score 0):

With C&K, it should be 13pts FTW.  Even with Harbor Master, it shouldn't up that

Harbor Master gives you 2pts, and with only 2p, there should be enough room to build and get to 13 or 15.

If it really does drag on, consider calling it after x # of time, or the next time the Barbarians strike.